# Q: SSRS Multivalued Parameters effecting query results

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012

I have 2 different date.year parameters on 2 different datasets. The datasets are Identical to eachother. This enables me to compare the same 2 columns from different years in one table. The problem is that whenever the parameters are multi-valued they seem to effect the values of the rows I want to compare to eachother. The table generally seems inconsistant when switching around the parameters.

These records are fine
[image]

This is the problem 
[image]

Comment: Could you provide more information, such as what form the tables take, what the parameters are, and how the multi-selection affects them.  Thanks

Comment: Check my edit, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The data sets are not identical, at least not quite. At first I thought it might be a mapping issue between the parameter display value and the parameter value, that way you could have identical datasets that give different results. However looking at 2005 you see that the only difference is in the female columns for the partial HHigh School Group and Graduate Degree Group. Student gender is not a parameter (at least not a stated one), and it would be unlikely to get the same numbers for all other rows in the CY 2005 is the year were wrong.

Also it would be helpful if we could see the sql behind the report, specifically how the MVP is being populated.